# How to set object field from Thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm new in Spring and i trying to learn it with help Spring in action 5 (Craig Walls).I'm creating small  Spring Boot MVC-application.Now i have a little problem with Thymeleaf.

I have Controller,View and model as POJO object.When i'm trying to get data from form Intellij Idea told me that something wrong with my Thymeleaf view in this line:

```
Model
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import lombok.Data;


@Data
public class Taco {

    private Long id;

    private Date createdAt;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5, message="Name must be at least 5 characters long")
    private String name;

    @Size(min=1, message="You must choose at least 1 ingredient")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;


}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}"/>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Design your taco!</h1>
    <img src="../static/images/TacoCloud.png" alt="TacoCloud.png" th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}">

    <form method="POST" th:object="${taco}">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
                <h3>Designate yor wrap:</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient:${wrap}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>

                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
            <h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
            <div th:each="ingredient: ${protein}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span>
            </div>
        </div>


            <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
                <h3>Choose your cheese:</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient:${cheese}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
                <h3>Determine your veggies:</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
                    />
                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
                <h3>Select your sauce:</h3>
                <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
                    <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"
                    />
                    <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Name your taco creation:</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name"  th:field="*{name}"/> 

            <br/>
            <button>Submit your taco</button>
        </div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import tacos.Ingredient.Type;
import tacos.Ingredient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import tacos.Taco;
import tacos.data.IngredientRepository;

import javax.validation.Valid;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
public class DesignTacoController {

    private final IngredientRepository ingredientRepo;

    @Autowired
    public DesignTacoController(IngredientRepository ingredientRepo){
        this.ingredientRepo=ingredientRepo;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public String showDesignForm(Model model) {

        List<Ingredient> ingredients=new ArrayList<>();
        ingredientRepo.findAll().forEach(i->ingredients.add(i));

        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
            model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
                    filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }

        return "design";
    }


    private List<Ingredient> filterByType(
            List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
        return ingredients
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processDesign(@Valid @ModelAttribute("design") Taco design, Errors errors, Model model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "design";
        }

        // Save the taco design...
        // We'll do this in chapter 3
        log.info("Processing design: " + design);

        return "redirect:/orders/current";
    }

}
```

And finally i get this error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/design.html]")

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "design" - line 64, col 45)
```

Comment: what is there on line 64 on your html ?

Comment: I'm sorry.This one <input type="text" name="name"  th:field="*{name}"/>

Comment: Col 32 starts here th

Comment: change `<form method="POST" th:object="${taco}">` to `<form method="POST" th:object="${design}">`

Comment: It works, but incorrect input ok but another page part doesn't work( Why i should change taco to design?

Comment: you are missing `th:action` on your form as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two thing in code:

1. I  do not find any  action your  form in html. You should use `th:action` tag to add an action.
2. in html you used `th:object="${taco}"` for declare an object for your html form. But you do not add “taco” object in your model in controller method from where you return the html design. You should add the “taco” object in your controller method like below.

   model.addAttribute(“taco”, taco Object);

Comment: Thank's for your help.I solved problem.You was right.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed two things on your code.

1. I don't see `th:action` on your form that is required for form submission.
2. change `form method="POST" th:object="${taco}"` to `form method="POST" th:object="${design}"`

Try fixing these two and it should work.

Comment: What you mean another part of page ?

Comment: How you can see i getting data from database and showing them at view with help this construction <div th:each="ingredient: ${protein}">
                <input name="ingredients" type="checkbox" th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
                <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span>
            </div>

Comment: and this doesn't work if i replace th:object to th:object="${design}"

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying. Take a look at thymeleaf docs. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same issue.

Resolution for me was to add getters in Taco.java for name. Somehow lombok is not generating getters automatically at run time.

And `th:object="${taco}"` should be `th:object="${design}"`

No need to make changes for `th:action`. From tutorial

> If you take another look at the  tag in your view, you can see that its method attribute is set to POST. Moreover, the  doesn’t declare an action attribute. This means that when the form is submitted, the browser will gather up all the data in the form and send it to the server in an HTTP POST request to the same path for which a GET request displayed the form—the /design path.